# SCIP: how to compare objective values of two SCIP_SOLs?

Tags: scip

Is there a function that can compare two SCIP_SOLs and determine whether one SCIP_SOL is more optimal than the other?

I am hoping to use this in a branching rule using the solutions in the solution pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the objective value of a solution you need to call [`SCIPgetSolOrigObj()`](https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.0/html/group__PublicSolutionMethods.php#gac9efcb03da88bb6acf38f69bd5598af0). SCIP will automatically store the best found solution - call [`SCIPgetBestSol()`](https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.0/html/group__PublicSolutionMethods.php#ga5978378526107a47fb4965d0167a65d6) to get it.

There is no such thing as a "more optimal" solution. If you want to compare solutions based on something other than their objective values you need to implement that metric yourself.

Comment: It would be better to use `SCIPgetSolObj()` within the transformed space in the case of a branching rule, which saves the case distinction between minimization and maximization.